# Should I raise concerns about the quality of work an intern is producing?

Tags: software-industry, internship, software-development

I am a developer in a small team of 3 developers and one intern.  The intern is on a 12 week contract with us.  He has been assigned a small project however he has very little development experience.  I have encouraged him to raise any questions & concerns with myself however he has been rather quiet.

Recently I became concerned with the lack of communication so I sat down with him and went over his work.  The quality of his work is of significant concern.  Under normal circumstances I would avoid raising this concern with management as I don't see it as my place, however going forwards the application will manage a critical business process & I have my doubts about the maintainability & future development of the application.

In summary should I raise my concerns with management and if so in what manner?

**Update**: 
I had an informal chat with my manager and I raised it with him.  Turns out he already had similar concerns and was planning on moving him onto his own project.

Comment: What level of quality are you expecting out of an intern?  Why is an intern working on critical business applications?

Comment: I am not management and therefore I cannot answer that question.  All I can do is raise my concerns.

Comment: perhaps that is the question you might ask.

Comment: I have concerns that you are actually _expecting a intern to produce anything of quality on a critical software_. Interns should be used for smaller tasks and groomed into professionals that you can actually use before putting them _near_ sensitive code.

Comment: *checked to see if it wasn't about me*

Comment: "Interns on Critical Projects" is a red flag so big you can see it from Mars without even squinting your eyes.

Comment: If you haven't assigned someone competent to regularly check up on the work of the intern and review their work, you're failing that intern and wasting their time. A company should put effort into assuring its interns learn good work habits and effective work strategies. It sounds like your company is doing the opposite and expecting high quality work product to result. Someone has massively dropped the ball.

Comment: In light of your update, do you want to broaden this out into a more general question so we can still get answers that could help people in a similar situation?

Comment: I was like this when I first started. I'll answer tomorrow about what worked for me..

Comment: I just want to put this out there - I am currently an intern (haven't even started college yet) and my company had faith in me, and so far I'm delivering a new project, mostly by myself, in something new to the company.

Comment: @T.Sar: I couldn't see it last time I was there... =P but more seriously, the line between "intern" and "full-timer" can be less than 1 year between finishing school and taking the job afterward. In other words, pretty thick or thin, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @Mehrdad I still wouldn't like if I discover that my bank uses fresh-out-of-college people to create their "secure app for online transactions", tho.

Comment: @T.Sar: These are tech companies, not heavily-regulated businesses like banks. Not that banks are already doing security better than tech companies anyway.

Comment: @Mehrdad Worse yet :P How would you feel if you discovered that the Security Team for WhatsApp, Snapchat of Facebook was managed by a single Intern with an unlimited supply of pizza and redbull?

Comment: Can't believe these top comments criticizing the OP and questioning his judgement.

Comment: It would appear my role has been rather misinterpreted.  I am not the employer or PM and the intern is not my charge.  I am simply, a developer who noticed things where going awry.  But none the less the entire conversation has taken on its own rather interesting persona.  In my eyes I have done everything I can, its now in managements hands.

Comment: @User1255879 - Define what critical means here?  Are lives at risk? Is the system part of a legally required and audited sytem? is the system one that the business will not be able to function? Or is it just a system that helps improve the core business but if the system failed there are ways to work around it?

Comment: The rational way to plan for interns is to assume they will produce **nothing** of any value to the company. The point of an internship is that the intern learn about real life, not that they produce useful output. You get your "return on investment" by making the good ones a job offer they want to accept!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, you should.

If this project is going to be touching anything critical, then it is your duty to protect that process.  I'd raise the issue ASAP and suggest that the intern be reassigned to something less mission-critical.

If the intern is worth saving, phrase your concerns in a way to make it about having **ANY** intern on critical systems, which IMO is a valid thing to raise regardless.

Raise it in an email or in person.  Either way, include specifics.  Point out that he simply does not have the background for the task at hand and that his assignment to this project is a poor use of his skillset.  Suggest another project for him if you know of one that is a better match for his skills.

IMO, this is not the fault of the intern, but of management who put him outside of his depth.  You don't throw a weak swimmer into deep water one mile offshore.

The intern is on a mission critical situation. First: protect the company from that. Second, find a home for him, and then after that, train him up.

The immediate problem is that he has been placed in a bad situation. I wouldn't even put an untested Junior on mission critical projects, much less an intern.

Getting the intern out of a position where he can only fail is addressing a very serious concern about potential damage. That has to come first, take care of the intern after that, but ONLY after that

Comment: Agreed.  The intern should not be put in the position of working on a critical system IMHO.

Comment: To mis-quote something I remember from a somewhat similar case: "If the Intern is able to royally screw things up then you, as a company, have failed."

Comment: @MisterPositive If I were a "higher up" in that company, I would have quite a few questions about the wisdom of the management who decided to put an intern on a critical system.  What next, handing out loaded handguns to the kids on "take your child to work day"?

Answer (score 22):

**Is this intern in the right place, on the right project?**

If not, try to help him out. You are in quite a small team so I believe you see the intern quite often. He is an intern for a reason, to learn. So help the intern out!

**It IS in your right to raise concern**, but make sure you or someone else have given the intern all the help you can give him, because again, he is there to learn.

**A tip**

Go sit down with the intern again, state your concern, and ask what he thinks about it. He might be an intern but he is not brainless. If the intern is motivated, try to teach him some of the basics about whatever language you are using at work.

Comment: This 1000x this!

Comment: Helping the intern and safeguarding the integrity of mission critical systems are two different matters and it seems like they could be at odds here. While these are good points to raise, you'd ultimately just be postponing a difficult decision. Right now the internship and the code base might still both be salvaged. If the OP delays a real response that might no longer be the case.

Comment: Why is it his right to raise a concern? In what way is he affected in his work by the intern?

Comment: I agree, help the intern improve. An intern is not a cheap employee, the company provides a learning environment and may or may not get something in return.

Comment: This answer is misguided. I don't know whether you're in the industry or not, but modern software development is extremely complex. Whatever programming language the company is using, I can guarantee you it is not the problem. The real issues are more likely: unfamiliar libraries, third-party integrations, undocumented dependencies, spaghetti code, legacy architecture, formal review process (or lack thereof), etc.

Comment: I am in the industry, I have been an intern and I have had other interns in the company I work for. The reason why it's an intern, again, is because he is there to learn. The company agrees for the intern to work and **learn** there, the company is (at least in my country) provided with a payment for taking an intern in. The company is also in charge of making sure nothing goes wrong, but the intern has nothing to do with that. If things go bad, the company should look at itself, NOT at the intern.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter whether an intern or a regular employee is involved. If you have concerns about a **critical component** not being implemented correctly, you'll be doing your manager a favor by expressing your concerns as soon as possible.

Just try not to sound like you're blaming someone. State the facts which make you believe the project is off track, and suggest solutions if you can think of any.

BTW, I don't see a problem with letting an intern work on a critical component, if done right. That's how you find bright heads you'll want to hire by the end of the internship, and keep them motivated by making them feel they are making a difference. We had one such intern recently, and he's one of the devs now. If you give your intern a toy project, you'll only get an option to hire a toy developer.

Comment: I really appreciate the perspective of this answer.  My first though would be never to put an intern or entry level person on a critical project, but you have changed my mind in that it can be done, albeit carefully.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

The law [restricts what an intern can work on](https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs71.htm), among other things. The work performed is actually for the ***benefit of the intern***; it should provide education or experience in his chosen field of study, should not be for the benefit of the company, and should not displace regular employees.

It sounds like all of these rules are being broken. He isn't primarily a programmer; he isn't learning about whatever his field is; and he is doing work alone, on mission-critical systems, potentially displacing an actual paid employee.

If the internship is an unpaid position in the United States, it sounds like this situation is AGAINST THE LAW. If you are from some other country, check the applicable laws.

Comment: OP claims to be based in Scotland.  Are you asserting that this situation is against Scottish law?

Comment: Oops there I go being Americanocentric and assuming! No, I don't know the law there.

Comment: That's OK.  Your answer will no doubt be useful to _somebody_.  But you might like to edit it, just to clarify that you're talking about the United States.

Comment: This only applies to **unpaid** interns, which is really uncommon in the USA anyway.  If the intern is being paid at least minimum wage, then they can be made to do real work, regardless of their title.

Answer (score 0):

First off, **yes, you need to speak with your manager.** You have a real problem: an intern is creating code that you have concerns you won't be able to maintain. This is a legitimate risk to the company and your efficiency and is worth addressing.

However, when you have this conversation with your manager, it should not be one that blames the intern. The conversation should focus on the question of **how to increase the quality of the work**. As an intern, it's expected that left to their own devices, they will not be able to produce code of the same quality as a develop who has been in the industry for several years. They simply don't have the experience to do so.

The only real solution to this problem is to start giving the intern the guidance they need to write higher quality code. This person is *still learning*, and they will not learn efficiently without guidance. (Notably, it is rather unlikely that their formal education has really prepared them for the workforce.) While putting the intern on work that is less critical will reduce the risk to the company, it won't solve the underlying problem that the intern is not receiving any guidance.

Some ideas you can take into the meeting to offer:

- Frequent code reviews of some kind
- Daily updates (scrums)
- Targeted work that will give them an opportunity to practice specific technologies or design practices

Your goal should be to get the manager to agree to invest in this intern's learning. It doesn't necessarily have to be you that spends this time, but *someone* needs to. If the manager is unwilling to do this, then they are choosing to accept low quality work, frustrated employees who have to maintain or replace it, and a frustrated intern. There really isn't a lot of in-between: either the company is willing to invest in helping the intern grow and is hoping to get a one-day capable employee, or the company is trying to use the intern as cheap labor and will get what it pays for.